# Displaying elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

When I want to display the elements of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$, I get the output in cycle form like this:
[image]

#### Is there a way I can display the group elements like this:

$\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$

and use this format for all further computations?

Comment: Do you mean like `GroupElements[CyclicGroup[9]][[All, 1]]`? Or `GroupElements[CyclicGroup[9]][[All, 1]] /. a_?NumericQ :> a - 1`? Or `GroupElements[CyclicGroup[9]] /. a_?NumericQ :> a - 1`? (*Mathematica* doesn't like this last one.)

Comment: @march: no, that's still in cycle representation. I just want the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Why don't you just use `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}` from the beginning and use the `Mod` function?

Comment: @march: that makes sense. I'll try it.

Comment: @march: Can you maybe show me how I store this group in a variable such that I can compute the subgroups and use other commands?

Comment: Here's the thing. I don't really know what you need to do with this. If you want automated group theory functionality, then use the *Mathematica* group theory functionality and live with the cycle notation. If you don't want that, then you need to write the the things yourself. And in that case, you can just define the subgroups: `wholeGoup = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`, `sub1 = {0,2,4,6,8}`, `sub2 = {0,4,8}`, `sub3 = {0,8}`, `sub4={0}`. As it is, your question is pretty ill-defined, I think.

Comment: @march: Yes, I wanted the group theory functionality but without the cycle notation. If that is not possible I stick to the cycle notation then.

Comment: @march: The thing is, when I want to display subsets of larger cyclic groups the cycle notation takes an insane amount of space

Comment: Agreed. If you're just working with cyclic groups, I'm willing to bet it's worth just writing your own group theory functions rather than wading through the morass that is *Mathematica*'s group theory functionality.